# Accessing HTML DOM after an AJAX XMLHttpRequest -jquery

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm updating my code from using the AJAX library in jQuery to AJAX and Javascript.

I'm having some challenges accessing the DOM of an an AJAX XMLHttpRequest.

I would like to access the data attribute and value of the setup_start_time class via BLUR event to eventually update my database. For now I'm sending the data to an alert.

The document setup2.php contains the setup_start_time class and it's successfully received from the server as I can see it on the html page however my blur addEventListener is not working. If I write the class into the HTML document I can access the data.

//Using AJAX library in jQuery

```
function fetchSetupDetails()  
{  
  $.ajax({  
    url:"fetchSetup.php?setup_id=<?php echo $setup_id ?>",  
    method:"POST",  
    success:function(data){  
      $('#liveFlowSetup').html(data); 

        //$('#result').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>"+equipActualFlowCount+"</div>");
      }  
    });  
}  
fetchSetupDetails();

function editSetupDetails(id, text, column_name)  
{  
  $.ajax({  
    url:"updateSetup.php",  
    method:"POST",  
    data:{id:id, text:text, column_name:column_name},  
    dataType:"text",  
    success:function(data){  
          //alert(data);
          $('#result').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>"+data+"</div>");
        }  
      });  
}
$(document).on('blur', '.room_id', function(){  
  var id = $(this).data("id1");  
  var room_id = $(this).val();  
  editSetupDetails(id, room_id, "room_id");  
}); 


//using AJAX & Javascript

  loadDoc("setup2.php", fetchSetup);
  loadDoc("flowItems2.php", fetchFlows);
  //editDoc("updateSetup.php",id, text, column_name, editSetupDetails );

  function loadDoc(url, updateText) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        updateText(this);
      }
    };
    xhttp.open ("POST", url, true);
    xhttp.send();
  } 

function editDoc(url, id, text, column_name, updateText) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    data = {id:id,text:text,column_name:column_name},
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        updateText(this);
      }
    };
    xhttp.open ("POST", url, true);
    xhttp.send(data);
  } 

  function fetchSetup(xhttp) {
    document.getElementById("liveFlowSetup").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
  }
  function fetchFlows(xhttp) {
    document.getElementById("liveFlowData").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
  }
  //function editSetupDetails(url,id, text, column_name) {} 

//
function setupStartTime(){
var id = this.getAttribute("data-id3");
var setup_start_time = this.value;
alert(id + setup_start_time);
};
//x =  document.getElementById("setup_start_time");
x =  document.getElementsByClassName("setup_start_time");
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].addEventListener("blur", setupStartTime, false);
}
//x.addEventListener("blur", setupStartTime, false);


//HTML setup2.php
<input  type="text" class="setup_start_time"  name="setup_start_time" value="12:00:AM" data-id3="12:00:AM">
```

I'm expecting to see an alert with this.value and data-id value of 12:00:AM

Comment: well do you bind the event handler after you add the elements to the page?

Comment: @epascarello Thanks for responding. I'm currently learning Javascript. It took me about 1 week to get the jQuery version working.  Now I'm trying to learn how to achieve the same without jQuery. I can't seem to figure out how to bind the event listener to the class. Could you please offer some examples.

Comment: The event listener had to go inside the ajax callback